# Looking for a word that means something you thought happened but it didn't

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a word that means something you thought happened but it didn't.

For example, you thought someone went missing but they just went for a stroll or they just went out and didn't notify anyone.
Is there a specific word for that or not?

Comment: The obvious answers would be *mistake* or *error* or some such.

*Presume, assume, suppose* might *explain* the *mistake* or *error*.

Anything like *Confabulation* or *false memory* would be way over the top.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example, I would suggest *false alarm*. This may be used whenever the thing that you thought happened is something bad, or something that requires action, if the reality is not as bad or does not require as urgent or as drastic action.

Answer (score 1):

The psychiatry term is "[Confabulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confabulation)" but that's rarely used.

A more common term would be a **false memory**.

Answer (score 1):

The word [**misassumption**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=misassumption&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=Pbr0WbSeM-eK8QfB4IWQCw) which finds mention under 'related forms' as a sort of  'false assumption' [assumption (noun): something taken for granted; a supposition]  at http://www.dictionary.com/browse/misassumption perfectly fits your case.

> Misassumption (noun): a wrongful or incorrect assumption

Source: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/misassumption

It is also literally a [**misinterpretation**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=misinterpretation) of what (might have) happened: Cambridge Dictionary Online defines it as

> to form an understanding that is not correct of something that is said or done

Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misinterpret

Random example: 'I made an idiotic **misassumption** based on the way [Alice and Bob](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) were interacting yesterday. Eve confirms I completely **misinterpreted** it! I feel stupid for thinking there was [anything between them](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=anything+between+them)...'

You can also find a number of words with similar meaning here [of which a word I appreciate as being particularly suitable to your case is **misapprehension**, although certain [definitions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misapprehension) suggest it is used more often to describe misinterpretation of ideas rather than events]:

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/misinterpretation

Answer (score 0):

*Presume, assume, suppose* come to mind. *Conclude* or *deduce*, if there was a reason you thought something happened. There may be something better for your specific example though.